# Improve my site performance

Tags: css, performance, caching, cdn, pagespeed

I have a static only site which is hosted on Google App Engine. Infront of this sits Cloudflare CDN.

I have ran Googles Page insights to give me an idea how my website is performing, it is not performing well according to Google. I want Google to see it is performing well for SEO purposes.

This is the report I get from Google:

[image]

2 types of recommendations come:

1) Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
Show how to fix

2) Leverage browser caching

For problem 1 I have tried many things I have read on Google. I have tried adding 'aync defer' to the link attribute. I have tried to make the media = print so that the browser would first render the html then apply the css later. I have tried moving the links to the stylesheets into different locations around the html document. Essentially I have tried to follow this: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery.

As of right now my html page (my website is just on static html page) structure looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- all links/references to css files and javascript files -->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My second issue is browser caching which I do not understand why I am getting this error. Google App engine caches the files and then on top of that Cloudflare CDN sets the cache headers (and also gzip) on the documents so that the browser caches it (below is the Cloudflare caching components turned on).

[image]

I can see the browser is caching the static files and using those cached files in chrome tools when I run the page:
[image]

This is really the first time I have created a production static website so I may be misunderstanding many things, but I am looking how eliminate those 2 issues.

Cheers

Comment: "it is not performing well according to Google" - irrelevant. How does it perform? The page speed number is just a number.

Comment: It is extremely quick, in terms of user expierance I am not worried as the page load and renders almost instantly. I am just concerned because I got a ranking of 67/100 for performance from Google . If Google sees the page as slow (even though it is not) my SEO suffers.

Comment: I *think* Google doesn't use the performance number for its ranking. The number is just for the developer to get the site faster. Google wants speed and readability, (and people too), those matter. If you got that, don't worry. And test! Try it on every phone you can find. Etc

Comment: What's the URL?  Make sure all CSS and fonts come before any JS.  It is rare that JS needs to be in the <head>, JS should be placed after the HTML.  Google probably thinks 2 days is too short for cache.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if google is measuring this but it is often advised to load Bootstrap and Jquery from the following addresses as they are used by a lot of website and hence are already in browsers caches even if they never visited your website. (The same can certainly be found for font-awesome).

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/YOUR_BOOTSTRAP_VERSION/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/YOUR_BOOTSTRAP_VERSION/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/YOUR_JQUERY_VERSION/jquery.min.js"></script>
```